# Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'Firestore' error in Firebase Firestore with Firebase v9 modular syntax

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a React application that utilizes Firebase Firestore for database operations. I've recently upgraded to Firebase version 9 and have switched to the modular syntax to import Firebase services.

However, I encountered an error while trying to access the collection method in Firestore. The error message is "Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'Firestore'."

Here's my code snippet:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { FormEvent } from "react";
import contactcss from "./Contact.module.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import Card from "../../components/ui/Card";
import {
  faInstagram,
  faFacebook,
  faLinkedin,
  faDiscord,
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import emaillogo from "../../resources/email-logo.png";

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
//import { randomString } from "../../App";

// testing config toggle
let isTesting = true

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// testConfig goes here
const testConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyD1Z8u6LAQDrwBAd-t-aMzoYFpgrfjFH0E",
  authDomain: "gdscusyd-test.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "gdscusyd-test",
  storageBucket: "gdscusyd-test.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "430942619633",
  appId: "1:430942619633:web:e4b3661fac99d31cd5e650",
  measurementId: "G-DCF0X0L8QY"
};

// prodConfig goes here
const prodConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCdgEs7mefO_Woe3UJA7lgdlrtiqjpmfCI",
  authDomain: "gdsc-usyd.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://gdsc-usyd-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "gdsc-usyd",
  storageBucket: "gdsc-usyd.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "971303209941",
  appId: "1:971303209941:web:a6d9fa662f48a20916cb5c",
  measurementId: "G-HB1NEN3G3J"
};

let appConfig = isTesting ? testConfig : prodConfig;

// Initialize Firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp(appConfig);

// Initialize db
const db = getFirestore(app);


// generate random string of specified length
export function randomString(length: number) {
  var result = '';
  const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
}
​
return result;
}
​

export async function sendData(data: any, id: string) {
  await db.collection('contact-form').doc(id).set({ content: data });
}

​
const processData = async (event: FormEvent) => {
event.preventDefault();
​
// @ts-ignore
const elementsArray = [...event.target.elements];
​
const data = elementsArray.reduce((acc, element) => {
  if (element.id) {
    acc[element.id] = element.value;
  }
​
  return acc;
}, {});

try {
  if (data.name === '') throw("Name cannot be left empty")
  if (data.email === '') throw("Email cannot be left empty")
  if (data.message === '') throw("Message cannot be left empty")
​
  await sendData(data, randomString(10))
}
}

function Contact() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className={contactcss.background}>
          <img
            className={contactcss.emaillogo}
            src={emaillogo}
            alt="Contact Us"
          />
          <div className={contactcss.contact}>Contact Us</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Card
        title="We're keen to hear from you!"
        imageUrl="https://images.app.goo.gl/D6m6hHMnP1gjsKKV7"
        body=""
        /* onSubmitForm={submitFormHandler} */ // Placeholder comment
      />

      <div className={contactcss.whitebackground}>
        <div className={contactcss.socials}>
          <h1>Follow Our Socials</h1>
          <p className={contactcss.socialmedia}>
            Stay connected with GDSC USYD by following us on our social media
            channels:
          </p>
          <div>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gdscusyd/">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.instagram}
                icon={faInstagram}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gdsc.usyd">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.facebook}
                icon={faFacebook}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://discord.com/channels/872033047652990986/872033047652990989">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.discord}
                icon={faDiscord}
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/gdsc-usyd/">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className={contactcss.linkedin}
                icon={faLinkedin}
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

I have imported initializeApp, getFirestore, collection, doc, and set from Firebase's modular syntax as per the migration guide, but I'm still getting the error.

I've tried various solutions such as reordering the imports, rechecking my Firebase configuration, and updating my Firebase dependencies, but none seem to resolve the issue.

Could someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how I can properly access the collection method in Firestore with Firebase v9 modular syntax?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Please post your code as **text** and provide a [mre].

Comment: There are no link tags in your code, how are you expecting the routers to work?

Comment: Hi, please read [why you should not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Also, please don't add tags which are not related to the question. This question is about react, not about python, css, or html.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your Routes into a `<Switch>` Tag.

Your routes should look like this;

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
       <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/users">
       <Users />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this version in your app.js file (and please add your code as text, not image) :

```
import AllMeetupsPage from './pages/AllMeetups';
import NewMeetupPage from './pages/NewMeetup';

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component { 
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {};
 }

 render(){
   return (
     <BrowserRouter>
       <Routes>
         <Route path="/" element={<AllMeetupsPage />}/> 
         <Route path="/new-meetup/" element={<NewMeetupPage />}/> 
       </Routes>
     </BrowserRouter>   
   )
 }
}

render(<App></App>, document.querySelector('#root'));

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap your Routes into a `<Routes>` Tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but nothing is still showing up.. do you mean wrap <Routes> around all of the <Route></Route> tags?